# how to filter array where a key's value matches in php

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I'm not sure how to do this, but I would like to filter one set of data results while iterating through another.  What is the correct way to do this?  I am trying array_filter but I'm not sure I grasp how to make this work similar to a sql where statement:
edit: These below queries are to a MySQL database

```
    $arr_years = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, submodel_id, year FROM `subyears` ORDER by submodel_id", ARRAY_A);
    $arr_submodels = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, model_id, sub_name FROM `submodels` ORDER by model_id", ARRAY_A);
    foreach($arr_submodels as $submodel){
        $filtered = array_filter($arr_years, function ($value,$key){
            return $value == $submodel->id && $key == 'year';
        });
    //do something with $filtered here
    }
```

Basically I want the equivalent of "where submodel_id == id of the other array".
I think array_map might do what I want but I don't grasp that either, but if that is a better way please let me know and show me how?
Thanks.

Edit: added example output snippets of array's:
$arr_years:

```
array(50) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["submodel_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["submodel_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["submodel_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" } [3]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["submodel_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" } [4]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["submodel_id"]=> string(1) "6" ["year"]=> string(4) "2020" } }
```

$arr_submodels:

```
array(50) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["sub_name"]=> string(13) "RMK KHAOS 155" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["sub_name"]=> string(7) "RMK 144" } [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "4" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["sub_name"]=> string(11) "PRO-RMK 155" } [3]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["sub_name"]=> string(11) "PRO-RMK 163" } [4]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "6" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "22" ["sub_name"]=> string(11) "PRO-RMK 174" } [5]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "7" ["model_id"]=> string(2) "23" ["sub_name"]=> string(7) "SKS 146" } }
```

The reason I don't do this in the sql is I need to create a comma delimited list of years from the years table for each submodel id...it's a many to one relationship.

Thanks

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. You should also include example data, expected result and what result you're currently getting. It's hard to give suggestions when you don't know what the data set looks like or what the expected result should be or what you're currently getting.

Comment: I added what the data looks like, the expected result would be a filtered array of years...the ultimate goal is to get a comma delimited list of years from the years table where the submodel id matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on new information, this is what you likely want:

```
$arr = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sy.year) as years,
  sm.model_id as model_id,
  sm.sub_name as sub_name
  FROM `subyears` sy
  JOIN `submodels` sm
  ON sy.submodel_id=sm.id
  GROUP BY sm.model_id
  ORDER BY sm.model_id
");
```

The "years" column in the returned array will contain all of the years. By default, they are comma separated.

---OLD ANSWER BELOW---

You should do this in the query itself:

```
$arr = $wpdb->get_results("
  SELECT sy.id, sy.year, sm.id, sm.model_id, sm.sub_name
  FROM `subyears` sy
  JOIN `submodels` sm
  ON sy.submodel_id=sm.id
  ORDER BY sm.model_id
");
```

If you really insist on doing it outside the query, you need to create an entirely new array:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($arr_years as $year)
  foreach($arr_submodels as $submodel)
    if($year->submodel_id == $submodel->id)
      $arr[] = (object) array_merge((array) $year, (array) $submodel));
```

Now, $arr contains all the objects from the two arrays merged together where submodel_id == id. You can loop through $arr and do what you want.

I used array_merge because I don't know of any function to merge objects. If there is one, it will be more efficient.

Comment: The reason I don't do this in the sql is I need to create a comma delimited list of years from the years table for each submodel id...I could loop through and query the database each time to do this but thought those extra trips to the database would be expensive.

Comment: What is the database? MySQL? If so, you want group_concat. Show the data in  your question and the desired output. Indicate the database (if it is not MySQL). All of them have a way of concatenating multiple values in a group by clause.

Comment: Yes it is MySQL...I am showing the data now in the question, I wasn't aware of the group by clause and concatenating, I will look into that thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the order of the tables from your example to make it work like I wanted but the group_concat worked like a charm, learn something new every day.